# How to send email using phpmailer by fetching the email id and its smtp configuration from database

Tags: php, mysql, email, phpmailer

My php code for sending email using php mailer is

```html
$email=new PHPMailer();
$email->isSMTP();
$email->SMTPDebug = 0;
$email->SMTPAuth = true;
$email->SMTPSecure=$smtpsecure;
$email->Host=$host;
$email->Port=$port;
$email->isHTML(true);
$email->Username=$sender;
$email->Password=$password;
$email->setFrom($sender);
$email->addAddress($recver);
$email->addAttachment($filename);
$email->send();
```

in this I want to take all details from database like sender,receiver,host,port,securetype
I like to use different emails to send mails like gmail,yahoo,outlook etc,
so i need to fetch ths smtp configuration from database

I all the above code is not working
by putting smtp configurations directly it working fine,but while fetching from database not working

Comment: have you echoed out the variables to make sure they match?

Comment: Your mechanism is correct, it just sounds like what you are getting from your database is not what you think. When debugging any script, *check* your values, don’t assume they are correct.

Comment: I echoed   the variables,that was correct,but not working, i added the code if(!$email->send()){ echo "Not Send".$smtpsecure.$host.$port; } else { echo "Mail Sent"; }

Comment: `$email->SMTPDebug = 0;` change to 2-3 and see what it returns